# Writing a Modified OpenSSL Handshake Protocol

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

For a research project, I need to be able to collect the Diffie-Hellman parameters that are sent along with their signatures during the ServerKeyExchange phase of the SSL/TLS handshake.  To do this, I want to write a very basic version of the handshake protocol that stores the messages I need to keep.  However, as far as I can tell, the lowest level the OpenSSL library lets you go with the handshake protocol is the `SSL_do_handshake` function.  I tried looking through the source code to find out which functions `SSL_do_handshake` relies on, but I haven't found anything useful.  Assuming there is no function that lets me do this easily, what would be the best way to approach the problem: using the SSL standards (such as RFC5246) as a guide and sending raw bytes as the "handshake," running `openssl s_client -connect <website> -msg` and using `sed` to extract the messages, or something else?

Comment: Consider looking into libressl, they cleaned up the code considerably, making it potentially easier to understand.

Comment: If you can debug the code, that should help you find the area.  Consider an IDE which performs code analysis (e.g. on windows MSVS, source insight).  This shows where code flows without running

Comment: You're not clear: do you want to capture normal sending (on the server), receiving (on the client), or send some kind of fake? For the first two, you could use openssl with a message callback and/or a BIO callback, which is what `-msg` and `-debug` on `s_client` or `s_server` do, although for an openssl server the app logic selects the DHE parameters so you should already know what they are.

Comment: I wanted to capture normal sending and receiving.  We (a co-advisor and I) agreed that `openssl s_client -msg` plus text processing is the way to go, partly because I have neither the knowledge nor the time to reinvent the wheel.